# C# or C++ with WinAPI block ping request

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, networking, ping

I need to write a program that will monitor the ping requests coming to my computer and will block them(don't send back echo for ICMP) or a programm probably should block not the echo packets but the incoming ping packets.

Thank you!

Comment: a) Decide for *one* language. b) There are many complete firewall programs

Comment: I'm asking about two languages because I am not sure that C# can solve this problem. And I need a code solution I am not interested in complete firewalls.

Comment: As Windows has a built-in firewall with API, would that be acceptable? Starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd339599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Well I thought about something like working with sockets... But the link you gave is better than nothing. So thank you! But still it uses windows firewall and I would be happy to monitor traffic by myself... somehow...

Comment: What deviantfan said.  Use the Windows Firewall and it's associated API to configure it, it has everything you need including both blocking and monitoring.  Your code will need to run with elevated privileges (as admin).